# How to use matterJS in react native without react native game engine

Tags: react-native, matter.js

I have been using matterJS in react native with the help of RNGE for game development. But now i thing I dont need any loop in my game and RNGE is used for having loop feature in app. So want to add matterJS with out react native game engine

Comment: Your question is not clear... What specific problem are you facing? Are you getting any errors or messages? What have you tried and what was the result?

Also helpful to provide sample of code that you are having trouble with and what the specific difficulties you are facing with your code.

Comment: well, it is very simple one , i have googled it and found the way to use matterJs in react which is like as according to this link https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-use-matter-js-in-a-react-app-bbd43b71efcc but the issue is when i will have to use it in react native i am unable to find any good source, what i found is we can use is by wrapping it in a react native module called react native game engine (RNGE). My question is how to use matter js without using RNGE in app

Comment: why do you want to stop using RNGE?  Especially if you are developing game? At least for me they seem to live very well together..

Comment: Is there a problem with installing plain MJS, then using it as you normally would in a React project? What is your target for rendering -- `<View>` elements?